# If I uninstalled an app from Android like WhatsApp will the database still remain if so where

Tags: android, sqlite, in-app-purchase, uninstallation

I'm trying too figure out if the database on Android phones can still be seen in sqlite after the app is uninstalled the app I'm new too this

Answer (score 0):

In your situation the database **will** be deleted. There are applications where data can persist after deleting the app as the data may be stored in an external database as opposed to internal.

Comment: So if I were too do a forensic review of the internal memory I would not find thumbnails, artifacts  or databases for the app in sqlite using software such as oxygen and ufed as long as the app was deleted?

Comment: Is there a way too recover the data base?

Comment: After researching a bit I have found that it seems that it might be possible to recover the data. https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-recover-my-WhatsApp-database-if-it-has-been-accidentally-deleted-from-my-file-system-of-Android-mobile That link might be able to get you started

Comment: Actually it depends.  The local db will be deleted.  But cloud backups are a feature of Android, if enabled it would have automatically uploaded to the cloud.

Comment: I stated that directly in my answer @GabeSechan

Comment: @MarcusCantu This isn't about an external db.  My point is about the android:allowBackup flag on the Application in the manifest.  If not set to false explicitly, Android itself will back it up to Google Drive, should a google account be on the device.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup  So unless you take action to explicitly turn it off, it will be cloud saved for you automatically.  If you were depending on it being erased for security you shouldn't (they could have copied it first).  If you're just looking at space, the system will take care of it for you.